# Why cdkRowDefWhen in cdk table is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm trying to use a feature of angular material cdk tables, but I don't see it working, and maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
The feature is add a condition to show a row or not, and the cdk table provides it with the [cdkRowDefWhen](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/api#CdkRowDef).
So, to implement this, in my template I defined the cdkRowDef in this way:

```
<tr
  cdk-row
  *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; when: showRow"
  class="bm-rt-table-row"
></tr>
```

where showRow is defined in the component as

```
showRow(_index: number, row: Recording) {
  return !row.id //my condition
}
```

and it never even executes the showRow.
Am I doing something wrong?
I don't see open issues about this, so I suppose that shouldn't be a problem of the cdk.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need more than one cdk-row, the cdk-row template for which the 'when' function returns a true value will be displayed. So your code would look something like this.

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
displayedColumns1: string[] = ['id', 'name'];

showRowTemplate(_index: number, row: PeriodicElement) {
return row.id % 2 === 0
}

showRowTemplate1(_index: number, row: PeriodicElement) {
  return row.id % 2 !== 0 
}
```

```html
<tr
  cdk-row
  *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; when: showRowTemplate"
></tr>
<tr
  cdk-row
  *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns1; when: showRowTemplate1"
></tr>
```

In this example, the rows with odd ids will not have the weight and symbol columns but the even rows will